# Automated spam being caught in 2 posts. Can this be used to help get rid of spam on everyone's sites?

Tags: spam

I don't know why but I have two old posts that seem to be attracting spam from some automated system or bot. It doesn't bother me but is there a way to use this data to try and help reduce spam on everyone's sites?

I'm using Akismet and Really Simple CAPTCHA in Contact Form 7 to block most spam though.

Exploit Scanner was also installed just to see if there was anything weird in my site but everything looks clean so far.